# How to export a Shapefiles of an OpenStreetMap relation?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, export, josm, overpass-api

Given I have a relation such as [this example](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1631028). I have installed [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de) and [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org) as well as [GDAL tools](http://www.gdal.org) for the shell. I am aware of [Overpass-Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu). What is the best way to export geometry data from [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) into Shapefiles?

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to export exactly this one relation to a shapefile? or do you want more?

Comment: There may be not any generally best method but the OSM driver of GDAL http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html used with ogr2ogr http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html is a good candidate.

Comment: @underdark Yes, I only want to extract this relation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the Umweltzone using the following Settings in Quick OSM. Note that you can simply search for the name:

[image]

Afterwards, you can use Save as ... to save to a Shapefile (or just copy the temporary Shapefile Quick OSM creates).

Comment: Can I also refer to the relation id if there is no `name` tag given?

Comment: Surely: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_element_id. As an example: `rel(2003523); >; out meta;`

Answer (score 3):

If the relation or way in question is closed and tagged with `boundary="administrative"` or `boundary="political"` you might be able to use [MapIt: Global](http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/) for this - it's a reverse geocoder for administrative and political boundary data in OpenStreetMap. (This service is mostly used for looking up enclosing boundaries in OpenStreetMap from a given latitude and longitude, but you can also look up an OpenStreetMap boundary directly from its relation ID or way ID.)

The boundary in your question doesn't have those tags, but for other readers and use cases this might be helpful. For example, for [relation 62748](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/62748) you could construct the URL:

- http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/code/osm_rel/62748.html

... which redirects to:

- http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/area/979462.html

That page lets you download the boundary data in various formats: GeoJSON, WKT and KML. You could then convert it to ESRI Shapefile format with [`ogr2ogr`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) or [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/).

If you want to do that programmatically, it's easiest to leave off the `.html` from the URL above, to give http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/code/osm_rel/62748 - that redirects to http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/area/979462 and you can just append `.geojson` to that latter URL get the GeoJSON version: http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/area/979462.geojson

There are some restrictions to be aware of with this service:

- The database is only updated roughly quarterly, so the relation/way you want might be out of date or missing.
- The only boundaries included are:

  - Relations or ways that are closed
  - Relations or ways that are either:

    - tagged with `boundary="administrative"` and `admin_level` from `1` to `12`
    - or tagged with `boundary="political"` and `political_division` one of `linguistic_community`, `insular_council`, `euro_const`, `canton`, `circonscription_législative`, `parl_const`, `county_division` or `ward` (these could be extended for the next import with a pull request modifying [this file](https://github.com/mysociety/global.mapit.mysociety.org/blob/master/bin/get-boundaries-by-admin-level.py).

Comment: Mark, respectfully, I'd like to give you a big smooch for this one

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to extract features from osm database and save them to shapefiles, then I would suggest using Qgis with the quickOSM plugin.

With QuickOSM you can easilly query the Openstreepmaps database (it uses turbo overpass) and add the result to Qgis canvas while saving it to a shapefile.

Comment: Can you please extend your answer? I found *Quick OSM* and installed the plugin. However, I do not understand how I can query the relation given in my example with the tool.