# QuickOSM returns no result

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, polygon, quickosm

I am trying to download the polygons for the [Umweltzone Heidelberg](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2676846#map=13/49.4053/8.7036) from OpenStreetMap using [QuickOSM](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/) in QGIS. I queried by `name` as shown in the screenshot:

[image: QuickOSM]

The corresponding OSM script looks like this:

```xml
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="25"> 
     <id-query {{geocodeArea:Germany}} into="area"/> 
     <union>
          <query type="node">
               <has-kv k="name" v="Umweltzone Heidelberg"/> 
               <area-query from="area"/>
          </query>
          <query type="way">
               <has-kv k="name" v="Umweltzone Heidelberg"/> 
               <area-query from="area"/>
          </query>
          <query type="relation">
               <has-kv k="name" v="Umweltzone Heidelberg"/> 
               <area-query from="area"/>
          </query>
     </union>
     <union>
          <item />
          <recurse type="down"/>
     </union>
     <print mode="body" />
</osm-script>
```

The query runs successful however **no result** is returned.

I also tried to [download by relation id](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128059/how-to-export-a-shapefiles-of-an-openstreetmap-relation#comment183675_128091) running this query:

```
rel(2676846); >; out meta;
```

This downloads **two points** - nothing more.

How can I download the polygons for the Umweltzone Heidelberg?

Comment: Please open a new question with the detailed crash report or file a bug at the issue tracker or contact the author of the plugin via email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your query area `Germany` does not exist with that name. Using `Deutschland` and disabeling the timeout returns the data.

I zoomed around Heidelberg and ran the query successfully and much quicker, querying the extent of the map canvas.

[image: QGIS with QuickOSM]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to zoom before around Heidelberg and if you are pretty sure that only one object is called `Umweltzone Heidelberg`, you can set a quick query like this :

- key `name`
- value `Umweltzone Heidelberg`
- in : empty value.

This will create only an attribute query, not a geographic query. This kind of query is very quick.

```
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="25">
    <union>
        <query type="relation">
            <has-kv k="name" v="Umweltzone Heidelberg"/>
        </query>
    </union>
    <union>
        <item/>
        <recurse type="down"/>
    </union>
    <print mode="body"/>
</osm-script>
```

[image: QuickOSM]

Comment: You also unselected all object types except `Relation` to produce this query. In my case it running the query fails with the message: "No outputs selected".

Comment: On the left, it's the OSM object. Yes I selected only ``relation``. On the right, it's GIS geometry. We need to select at least one for the output. You can select all of them, it doesn't matter. You want to the ``multipolygons`` so check it.